# How to navigate inside a UITableView which is inside a popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

gotta a question regarding how to navigate inside the UITableView. Here is the situation: I have a popover which is a UITableView, and select a cell simply navigate to another view(detail view). What I need is on my detail view, after I select a cell, I want to navigate back to the previous view. I tryied

```
– popViewControllerAnimated: 
–popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animated:
```

and they did navigate back. However, the popover got dismissed after that. So I am wondering if anybody knows how to navigate back without effect the popover. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

popViewControllerAnimated: is the correct solution. That shouldn't hide the popover though - are you sure you're not hiding the popover with some other code?

Comment: Yes you are right, I did have a dismisspopover in another function so the logic is wrong. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pushed the detail view from the table view, then the default back button works the way you want. Have you changed to anything specific?

Comment: no it was my mistake to dismiss the popover in another method call. popViewControllerAnimated will do the trick. And no i didn't use the back button since the desired way is to navigate back after selecting a cell from the detailed table view. Thanks anyway.